# Why was Von Neumann architecture seminal?

Tags: architecture

While starting to read about computer architecture , I came across the statement :

"A major defining point in the history of computing was the realization in 1944–1945 that data and instructions to manipulate data were logically the same and could be stored in the same place. The computer design built upon this principle, which became known as the Von Neumann Architecture"

What was eclipsing this realization earlier and hence made it a seminal finding ? Basically , I wanted to know how was the thought process in coming up with an architecture .

P.S : Maybe , I have already known that in microprocessors instructions and data are stored in the same place and that's why I am missing the cream of this realization and I could have framed the question in a better way but it was in no way a question sarcastic intention on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the reason it's hard to see why it is seminal is that things can be obvious in hindsight.

The world was mostly mechanical at the conclusion of WW2 so intellectual concepts were modelled in mechanistic terms. Consider the concept of an "automaton" whereby a human-like machine (i.e. a robot) was made up of wheels and cogs and chains. These days our view of robots is hardware and software and the old automaton view is considered anachronistic. In future there may be a new way of doing information processing that is different and our view of a robot might seem quaint.

So in terms of data processing, maybe they were thinking along the lines of typewriters or something - the data is the writing on the paper and it required a typewriter to imprint the writing. If you've never known computers or computer memory or logic processing, viewing them as the same thing is actually quite a conceptual leap.

Comment: Now I see it . Thanks